# Nested ng-tranclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have the following code. I want to transclude at 3 different levels which I can't see why it wouldn't work

```
<div data-panel class="panel">
    <data-panel-heading>
        heading
    </data-panel-heading>
    <data-panel-content>
      content
    </data-panel-content>
</div>

var app = angular.module('mymodule', [])
.directive('panel', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    };
})
.directive('panel-heading', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="heading" ng-transclude></div>',
    };
})
.directive('panel-content', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="content" ng-transclude></div>',
    };
});
```

What I want to happen is something like this:

```
<div data-panel class="panel">
     <div ng-transclude>
       <div class="heading">
         heading
       </div>
       <div class="content">
         content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/CIZp7OzrPU5D6db0p7lK

Seems to be ignoring the heading and content templates. Any ideas how to get this working

Comment: I think your demo is working just fine.

Comment: This ignores the directive templates but I solved my own issue. 'panel-content' & 'panel-heading' in directive definition should have been: 'panelContent' & 'panelHeading' - camelCase
http://plnkr.co/edit/6AwfcGpyZGdAaRvaQ0Wg?p=preview